# Mcrypt not installed with Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, mcrypt, homestead

I've just moved from a WAMP installation to Homestead and I can't get my app running.

When running `composer install` I get this error:

```
Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128'
```

Many people seem to have problems with that but most of them use custom installation (they install php from scratch for example). I have just followed the steps [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead).

I tried to `grep` mcrypt from `php --info` and not a single line is returned so I assumed mcrypt is not install.

I've run `sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt` and it says:

```
php5-mcrypt : Depends: phpapi-20121212
```

I could try to install this dependency but I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong (the point of using Homestead was to get rid of everything but the project itself, I assume).

The php version used in the vm:

```
PHP 7.0.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0RC3, Copyright (c) 2002-2015, by Derick Rethans
```

(Not sure why it's php 7, I've never asked for that.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried installing running `sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt`? Trying to install `php5-mcrypt` will obviously not work since its for PHP 5.* :). As for why PHP7 is the default installation, there's really no confusion there as the [Homestead Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead#introduction) clearly states that the latest homestead comes with PHP 7 by default. If you would want to use PHP 5.6 you should clone the older Homestead `2.0` branch like this: `git clone -b 2.0 https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git`.

Comment: that was it! I got plenty of other errors after that but I eventually fixed them. Everything is working now, thanks ! ;-)

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Homestead with PHP7 does not support Laravel 5.0, out of the box.

As mentioned above in the comments this worked:

```
git clone -b 2.0 https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git
```